# Why is "keiner" masculine in this sentence? "Keiner sagt dir, was du tun sollst"

Tags: meaning, german-to-english, article

Why is "keiner" masculine in this sentence?

> "Keiner sagt dir, was du tun sollst"

Is "keiner" used instead of a specific name?

Comment: "Keiner" kann keinen Namen haben, dann wäre es "Einer". "Nobody" cannot have a name, it would be "Someone" otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Keiner* is a pronoun; the ending *-er* is masculine. One of the functions of the masculine is referring to persons, most clearly shown by interrogative *wer* (as opposed to neuter *was*, which refers to things; there is no feminine form).

> **Wer** hat seine Handschuhe vergessen?

Similar pronouns without a feminine form where the masculine refers to a person (note masculine *sein-* agreeing with the pronoun).

> Da hat **jemand/wer** seine Handschuhe vergessen.
> Natürlich hat **man** kalte Hände, wenn **man** seine Handschuhe vergisst.

Now, *keiner/einer/jeder* of course do have feminine forms that will usually be used when appropriate referents have been introduced.

> Von ihren drei Töchtern hat jed**e** Abitur gemacht.

But no such referent has been introduced in *keiner sagt dir, was du tun sollst*, hence the masculine.

Answer (score 3):

"Keiner" is a *generic masculinum*, traditionally used to express "There is no information whatsoever about the sex of the actor". This has recently been criticised for furthering sexist thought, but suggestions for replacement tend to concentrate on the more frequent expressions such as 'man', to the point where I don't even know what alternative would be preferred.

Comment: In feminist German you would say "Keiner und keine".